# Casbin: user may only call path with their own username

Tags: java, casbin

I'm trying to implement Casbin authentication so that a user can only get their own username, but apply this to a group. Example:

`/users/get/alice` can be called by user with username `alice`

`/users/get/john50` can be called by user with username `john50`

`alice` and `john50` can't call the other's endpoint.

However, I want to be able to apply this to all users within a group, so ideally I'd want my policy to look like:

`p, staff-all, /users/get/:userid, GET, allow`

Is this something I can implement in the policy and model or would I need to implement something in code? This sounds like a more complicated use case than having in the policy and model.

My current model:

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, act

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, act, eft

[role_definition]
g = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow)) && !some(where (p.eft == deny))

[matchers]
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && keyMatch2(r.obj, p.obj) && regexMatch(r.act, p.act)
```

I have seen something similar in the [Casbin examples](https://github.com/casbin/casbin/blob/master/examples/keymatch2_policy.csv) but these seem to give a specific username rather than done via groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `keyGet()` functions here: https://casbin.org/docs/en/function

The matcher will be something like:

```
m = (r.sub == keyGet(r.obj, p.obj)) && <other_part>
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Function not found: keyGet` error and I can't see `keyGet` in [here](https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/casbin/jcasbin/util/BuiltInFunctions.java). Is keyGet not supported in jCasbin?

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that we are using RBAC, but we want to be able to ensure that a user who is not part of an admin group can only access their own jobs

Comment: @JoshLaird keyGet() is currently only available in Golang, please send a github issue in jCasbin repo to request this feature in Java, we will help you there.

Comment: @JoshLaird added here: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin/issues/132

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give this a go